# How to find the install date of Windows operating system without the Registry or command prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-installation, forensics

I am looking at the dumped files of a Windows XP computer. I do not have access to the Registry, just all of the files from the computer itself. I want to figure out on what date the operating system was installed, but most responses online say to either look in the Registry or use the `systeminfo` command to find it (and the `systeminfo.exe` program obviously fails to run because it does not have the Registry to check for some parts of it).

**So is there a way to find what date Windows was installed without access to the registry?** What file does `systeminfo` check to retrieve that information? Or does it use the Registry?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the Windows folder from your dead PC as a backup, then you have all you need.

You can load the registry of a dead PC into your registry editor. After that, you can look under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\<deadRegistry>\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InstallDate
```

---

### Step by step

1. Open your registry editor (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> » regedit.exe)
2. Select `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
   <sub>(Strangely, this step is needed. Otherwise *File » Load Hive* is greyed out)</sub>
3. In your menu bar, click on *File » Load Hive...*
4. Navigate to and open

   ```
   <your Windows backup>\Windows\system32\config\SOFTWARE
   ```

   `SOFTWARE` is the file we want in our case since it holds the install date. But there are other files which contain other parts of your dead registry
5. A new key will be created under your HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key. Give it a meaningful name like *Dead PC Software Hive*

   [image]
6. Now you should be able to navigate to

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\<Dead PC Software Hive>\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
   ```
7. In the right pane you'll see a REG_DWORD called `InstallDate` and it's value. For example mine shows `59e074ec`. You can convert the HEX or DEZ value with [any online converter into a readable format](https://www.epochconverter.com/hex?q=59e074ec)
8. Don't forget to unload the hive once you’re done. Select the key *Dead PC Software Hive* and click on `File » Unload Hive...`

---

### Used resources

- [Accessing Another Windows Computer’s Registry from a Disk in Windows 8.1](https://jchornsey.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/accessing-another-windows-computers-registry-from-a-disk-in-windows-8-1/)
- [How to Determine the Windows Installation Date with and without PowerShell](https://www.sepago.de/blog/2009/09/24/how-to-determine-the-windows-installation-date-with-and-without-powershell)
- https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: This is perfect! Except that I run into the Windows SAM file being read-only when I navigate to it. [And it isn't because of a hibernation file](https://superuser.com/questions/1010229/recovering-a-windows-10-password-when-the-partition-is-read-only?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Answer (score 1):

The Event Viewer may shed light on this, so long as the logs go back to the system install.

In Windows XP, these would be .evt files stored in `%SystemRoot%\System32\Config`

You should be able to open these in the Event Viewer on a working Windows computer by right-clicking on the Event Viewer (Local) entry at the top of the tree, and selecting **Open saved log...**

Answer (score 0):

I've always done this in XP by going to C:\ in Explorer, right-clicking on the Windows folder, choosing Properties, and looking at the "Created" date.

So long as you're looking at the files from the original installation hard drive (as opposed to a backup that may have been created later), this should be accurate.

Comment: Couldn't do this, because the question was about dumped files from another computer so there is no Explorer program to launch.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Windows\Panther\ and have a look at the date of setupact.log or cbs.log !

That is date and time of the initial installation of Windows.